# Inflation layer costs: Polygonal vs. Circular Footprints

Tags: nav2, collision, footprint

Does the inflation layer calculate Inflation cost in global costmap differently within the inflation radius when initialized with a polygonal footprint versus a circular footprint?

Exclude the local costmap and footprint size.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The inscribed radius is used to create the `253` inscribed radius section which is known to be in collision if the center point is within it. When you change footprints, no matter how that footprint is shaped or defined, the `253` space will always auto-populate for the inscribed radius of the robot for collision checking.

The actual inflation after that point is unaffected. However, if your inflation radius / gain is set such that no inflation happens after the inscribed radius of the robot, then you won't see any potential field being formed.

Comment: Thanks for a clear answer, like always.

Comment: Can you mark it as correct to remove from unanswered questions queue?